# Unable to get data object using doctrine through api, when 'auth' middleware is not attached

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When I am making a API call to the http://localhost/lvl53/public/api/getSongs using Postman I get the following error.

FatalErrorException
Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory::getProxyDefinition(): Failed opening required.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNEhO.png

Here are my routes web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/song', 'SongController@index')->name('song');
    Route::get('/addSong', 'SongController@addSong')->name('addNewSong');
    Route::post('/registerSong', 'SongController@create')->name('registerSong');

});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Here is api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/getSongs', 'SongController@getSongs')->name('getSongs');
});
```

But if I add the API route getSongs to the Route::Group in web.php and after logging in make the call, then I am able to retrieve data.

Here's my SongController's getSongs method

```
public function getSongs(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $songs = $em->getRepository(SongEntity::class)->findAll();
        $songList = [];
        \Log::info(["Songs",$songs]);
        foreach ($songs as $song){
            $currentSong["artist"] = $song->getArtist();
            $currentSong["title"] = $song->getTitle();
            $currentSong["url"] = $song->getUrl();
            array_push($songList, $currentSong);
        }
        return $songList;
        /*return view('song.songs', ['songs' => Song::all()]);*/

    }
```

In here when making the api call \Log doesn't create a log. How to retrieve data using the API?
PS: When I looked into error msg they say I have do advance configurations on doctrine, it doesn't make sense. Any help is highly appreciated.

PPS: Do you think it has do something with attaching a authenticated user to SongEntity when creating the SongEntity?

Here's what happens when creating a SongEntity.

```
protected function create(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {

        $user = Auth::user();
        //\Log::info($user);
        $data = $request->input();
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'artist' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'url' => 'required|string|url|unique:App\Entities\SongEntity',
        ]);

        $song = new SongEntity(
            $data['title'],
            $data['artist'],
            $data['url'],
            $user
        );

        $em->persist($song);
        $em->flush();


       /* Song::create([
            'title' => $data['title'],
            'artist' => $data['artist'],
            'url'=> $data['url']
        ]);*/

        return redirect('song');

    }
```

Comment: I think you don't to specify 'web' middleware anymore. Try without it.

Comment: Still, doesn't work, problem is with auth middleware if I attached it then I can retrieve data after logging in

Comment: Can you regenerate the Doctrine proxies using `php artisan doctrine:generate:proxies`? (I presume you're using laravel-doctrine/orm)

Comment: THIS WORKED!!!, Could you please explain what really happened here? And how that adding auth module fixed the case temporaliy? And what are these proxies?